# PHPMailer getting details from input fields

Tags: php, email, system, phpmailer

im having issues getting data passed from input fields to the mail that is being sendt.

This is what i have so far:

```html
<?php
/**
 * PHPMailer simple contact form example.
 * If you want to accept and send uploads in your form, look at the send_file_upload example.
 */
//Import the PHPMailer class into the global namespace
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

if (array_key_exists('to', $_POST)) {
    $err = false;
    $msg = '';
    $email = '';
    //Apply some basic validation and filtering to the subject
    if (array_key_exists('subject', $_POST)) {
        $subject = substr(strip_tags($_POST['subject']), 0, 255);
    } else {
        $subject = 'No subject given';
    }
    //Apply some basic validation and filtering to the query
    if (array_key_exists('query', $_POST)) {
        //Limit length and strip HTML tags
        $query = substr(strip_tags($_POST['query']), 0, 16384);
    } else {
        $query = '';
        $msg = 'No query provided!';
        $err = true;
    }
    //Apply some basic validation and filtering to the name
    if (array_key_exists('name', $_POST)) {
        //Limit length and strip HTML tags
        $name = substr(strip_tags($_POST['name']), 0, 255);
    } else {
        $name = '';
    }
    //Validate to address
    //Never allow arbitrary input for the 'to' address as it will turn your form into a spam gateway!
    //Substitute appropriate addresses from your own domain, or simply use a single, fixed address
    if (array_key_exists('to', $_POST) and in_array($_POST['to'], ['tester','tester','tester'])) {
        $to = $_POST['to'].'@emailaddress.com';
    } else {
        $to = 'myemail@emailaddress.com';
    }
    //Make sure the address they provided is valid before trying to use it
    if (array_key_exists('email', $_POST) and PHPMailer::validateAddress($_POST['email'])) {
        $email = $_POST['email'];
    } else {
        $msg .= "Error: invalid email address provided";
        $err = true;
    }
    if (!$err) {
        $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->Host = 'send.one.com';                         // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = 'myemail@emailaddress.com';            // SMTP username (enter the email adress to send to)
        $mail->Password = 'xxxxxxxx';                       // SMTP password (enter the password for the email adress)
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $mail->Port = 587; 
        $mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
        //It's important not to use the submitter's address as the from address as it's forgery,
        //which will cause your messages to fail SPF checks.
        //Use an address in your own domain as the from address, put the submitter's address in a reply-to
        $mail->setFrom('myemail@emailaddress.com', (empty($name)? 'Contact form': $name));
        $mail->addAddress($to);
        $mail->addReplyTo($email, $name);
        $mail->Subject = 'Contact form: ' . $subject;
        $mail->Body = "Contact form submission\n\n" . $query;
        if (!$mail->send()) {
            $msg .= "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
            $msg .= "Message sent!";
        }
    }
}?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="da">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <!-- FontAwesome Link -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- My CSS File -->
    <link type="text/css" href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="bg-faded fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light" id="commRollover">
                    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNav">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">FORSIDE <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">JEG HJÆLPER MED</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="bogfoering-og-regnskab.html">BOGFØRING OG REGNSKAB</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="loebende-bogfoering.html">LØBENDE BOGFØRING</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="aarsregnskaber.html">ÅRSREGNSKABER</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="oprydning-af-regnskab.html">OPRYDNING AF REGNSKAB</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="raadgivning.html">RÅDGIVNING</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="regnskabsprogrammer.html">REGNSKABSPROGRAMMER</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">PROFIL</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="om-mig.html">OM MIG</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item active">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="kontakt.php">KONTAKT</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main>
        <form class="container contact-wrap" method="post" action="">
            <h2>Ønsker du hjælp, så kontakt mig her</h2>
            <br>
            <?php if (empty($msg)) { ?>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Navn</label>
                <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" id="name" aria-describedby="nameHelp" required>
                <small id="nameHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Angiv gerne dit fulde navn. Det gør det lettere for mig at komme i kontakt med vedkommende</small>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="to">Email</label>
                <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" required>
                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Din email vil aldrig blive videregivet</small>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="number">Tlf. nr.</label>
                <input name="number" type="number" class="form-control" id="number" min="1" max="8" required>
                <small id="numberHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Dit telefon nummer vil aldrig blive videregivet</small>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <select name="to" id="to">
                <option value="tester">test1</option>
                <option value="tester" selected="selected">test2</option>
                <option value="tester">test3</option>
                </select><br>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="subject">Emne</label>
                <input name="subject" type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" required>
                <small id="subjectHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Beskriv kort, hvad din henvendelse drejer sig om</small>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="query">Besked</label>
                <textarea name="query" class="form-control" id="query" rows="10" required></textarea>
                <small id="queryHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Jeg vil besvare din besked så hurtigt som muligt</small>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <label class="form-check-label">
                            <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" required>
                                <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                                <span class="custom-control-description">Bekræft alle felter er udfyldt</span>
                            </label>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send besked</button>
        </form>
<?php } else {
    echo $msg;
}?>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <div id="footer">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                        <div class="footer-text">
                            <span>Talknuseriet IVS</span>
                            <span>Vestergade 31 </span>
                            <span>4990 Sakskøbing</span>
                            <br/>
                            <span>Cvr: <a href="https://datacvr.virk.dk/data/visenhed?enhedstype=virksomhed&id=38746820&soeg=38%2074%2068%2020" target="_blank">38 74 68 20</a></span>
                            <span>Telefon: (+45) 60 16 40 34</span>
                            <span>Email: <a href="kontakt.html">cb@talknuseriet.dk</a></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Talknuseriet" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

im trying to do this by using phpmailer system.
The only issue i have is when i try to gather the details from the input fields, i get this error code:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function isSMTP() on null in /.../kontakt.php:51 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /.../kontakt.php on line 51

For me, it seems the data isn't passing through to the email so the email isn't sent, it just delivers an error message instead.

I hope you guys can help me figure this one out.
My php isn't really good, but im trying.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you're missing ... $mail = new PHPMailer();

Comment: Add $mail = new PHPMailer; code after require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

Comment: If you read the error message it does tell you exactly what's going wrong: `Call to a member function isSMTP() on null` which if you view `$mail->isSMTP();` and work back clearly means that `$mail` is `null`, therefore ask yourself why it is null and you will find [Chris' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45925487/phpmailer-getting-details-from-input-fields#comment78809627_45925487) will fix this.

Comment: haha :D after looking at the code for over 3hours i guess i completely forgot about new PHPMailer();

Thanks a bunch. it finally works